# My React app enters into an endless loop once I press the button

Tags: reactjs, axios

I working on a little web app using the React and the Axios.

When the app first loads itself, it looks fine in my eyes.

But if I press the button, it will enter into some kind of endless loop for it just keeps acting like the user is constantly pressing the button over and over. The only way to to stop it, is to refresh the page.

I am not sure why it's doing it. Right now it is just using test data because I'm trying to reduce the complexity to see if I can figure out what's causing the error.

But so far, I can't figure it out.

Here is my simple code:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class ThoughtDeducer extends React.PureComponent {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        thoughts: "I am not here"
    };

}

shareYourThoughts = () => {
    var test = "I am in here";
    return axios.put("/sendto/api/saveThoughts", JSON.stringify(test), {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }).then((r) => {
        this.setState({...this.state, ...{thoughts: test}
        });

    })
}


render() {
    const { thoughts } = this.state;
    return (
       
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.shareYourThoughts}>Share Your Thoughts</button>;
            <div>{ thoughts }</div>
        </div>

    );

}
```

}

Comment: We can't hit that endpoint, but replacing the Axios call with `Promise.resolve` I don't see any looping behaviour.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, do you mean just do a `Promise.resolve(r) => {` instead of a `.then(r) => {`?

Comment: That wouldn't be syntactically valid, `Promise.resolve("whatever").then(() => { ...`